# How to build a string from key/value pairs in dict

Tags: python, string, dictionary

If I have a dictionary such as:

```
clues = {'w':'e','r':'t'}
```

How do I get the first of each letter in the two to join together in a string, it is something like...

```
for clue in clues:
   clue = ''.join(
```

However I don't know how to get them into a string from this...

Comment: By "first of each letter" do you mean the keys?

Comment: Just to make sure, you know that dictionaries don't have order and so in principle you could get `'rw'` just as easily as you could get `'wr'`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

You can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for that:

```
>>> clues = {'w':'e','r':'t'}
>>> [''.join(x) for x in (clues, clues.values())]
['wr', 'et']
>>>
```

---

---

> how would you get the first of each letter in the two to join together
>   in a string

I think you are talking about the dictionary's keys.  If so, then you can use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> clues = {'w':'e','r':'t'}
>>> ''.join(clues)
'wr'
>>>
```

---

Also, iterating over a dictionary (which is what `str.join` is doing) will yield its keys.  Thus, there is no need to do:

```
''.join(clues.keys())
```

---

Finally, @DSM made a good point.  Dictionaries are naturally unordered in Python.  Meaning, you *could* get `rw` just as easily as you get `wr`.

If you want a dictionary with guarunteed order, check out [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: i want W,R together and E,T together because trying to do a codebreaker programme

Answer (score 1):

And if you want all the keys joined into a string, try this:

```
''.join(clues.keys())
```

Comment: The `.keys` call is redundant.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: How? When treated as an array, do Python dicts evaluate to their keys?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Huh. `import makethismakesense` :). (I know very little about Python, thanks).

Comment: @Linuxios and for added fun, `.keys()` in Python 2.x will return you a list, while in Python 3.x, it will return you a view object... So for iteration purposes it's noise :)

Comment: @JonClements: Ok. Thanks. Take me back to Ruby... :)

Comment: Though in Python 2 `str.join` will be faster with `.keys`, as `str.join` works better with a list than an iterator.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I like being right by accident. What changes in Python 3?

Comment: @Linuxios `.keys` returns a View object rather than a list in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what your question is, but if you want to `join` the `key` and `value` together, storing that result into a new `set`, this would be the solution:

```
>>> {''.join(key_value) for key_value in clues.items()}
set(['rt', 'we'])
```

Written long hand for clarity:

```
out_set = set()
for key_value in clues.items():
    key_value_joined = ''.join(key_value)
    out_set.add(key_value_joined)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
''.join(clues.keys())
```